How to keep VSCode from resetting its `.desktop` file when updating on Linux?
I have my VSCode .desktop set up a certain way, but VSCode keeps resetting it whenever it updates. How can I keep VSCode from overwriting that file when updating?
(OS: Linux Mint)
Edit: Installed via the .deb package at https://code.visualstudio.com/

how are you installing? Snap? apt?

Edited, installed via the .deb from https://code.visualstudio.com/

From the Arch Linux wiki:

Modify desktop files
For system-wide .desktop files (e.g. those installed from a package), first copy the relevant .desktop file (e.g. from /usr/share/applications/) to $XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/ (e.g. ~/.local/share/applications/). This prevents your changes from being overwritten when the package gets updated during system upgrades. The local user-specific .desktop files should automatically take precedence over the system-wide files. Now you can modify the local user-specific .desktop file as needed.

